# Multiple API calls simultaneously in marionetteJS

Tags: api, marionette

I use forcast api to get weather data. In marionette I use model to define API rulRoot as

```
var weatherApi = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
                lat:"",
                lng:"",
                timeStamp:"",
                units:"",
                response:""
        },
        urlRoot: function(){
                return '/api/web/forecast?lat='+ this.get("lat") + '&long=' + this.get("lng") +'&time=' + this.get("timeStamp") + '&units='+this.get("units");
        }
});
```

Then I instantiate as

```
weatherApiGddObj = new weatherApiInstance();
```

I used this object to fetch api call response. Now want I want is to make multiple api call simultaneously like from today to next 30 days, So If I do one after another then It'll take lot of time to get all response. How do I do this with marionette?

Comment: marionette does not extend BB models functionality. It upgrade View and add you top level architecture blocks.

Comment: This is not a Marionette question. It should be tagged as Backbone. Also, are you not aware of how javascript XMLHTTPRequests objects (aka AJAX calls) work? It's asynchronous so you won't be waiting for one to finish before you can send another. Just send them all one after the other and then handle the response asynchronously. If you need the RESPONSES all together, use [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to have a method that allows you to grab data for the range of days in one request. But according to your conditions I'd do it like this:

```js
var date, startDate = someTimestamp, day = 86400, 
    endDate = startDate + day * 30, promises=[];

for(date = startDate; date < endDate; date += day){
    weatherApiGddObj.set('timestamp', date);
    promises.push(weatherApiGddObj.fetch());
}

$.when.apply($,promises).done(function(){
    var data = Array.slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I suggest you to read about [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)